# "The object invoked has disconnected from its clients " by adding page in multipage

Tags: excel, vba

When I try to add page in Multipage 1 , it works but it doesnt work in multipage2 , they are together in a userform. Could someone tell me where the Problem is.

```
If MultiPage1.Visible = True And OberbaudickeRStO.ComboBox1.Text = Label2.Caption Then
     With OberbaudickeRStO.MultiPage1
        For i = 1 To anzahl
     .Pages.Add
     .Pages(MultiPage1.Value).Controls.Copy
     Set MyPage = MultiPage1.Pages.Item(i)
     MyPage.Paste
      For Each ctl In MultiPage1.Pages(i).Controls
        Select Case TypeName(ctl)
            Case "TextBox"
            ctl.Text = ""
            End Select
        Next ctl
         Next i
        End With
End If

If MultiPage2.Visible = True And OberbaudickeRStO.ComboBox1.Text = Label13.Caption Then
   With OberbaudickeRStO.MultiPage2
     For i = 1 To anzahl
     .Pages.Add
     .Pages(MultiPage2.Value).Controls.Copy
     Set MyPage = MultiPage2.Pages.Item(i)
     MyPage.Paste
      For Each ctl In MultiPage2.Pages(i).Controls
        Select Case TypeName(ctl)
            Case "TextBox"
            ctl.Text = ""
            End Select
        Next ctl
         Next i
        End With
        End If
```

Comment: I can definitely reproduce the error.  It seems that it has nothing to do with the code for MultiPage2.  The error occurs when there are two multipage controls on the same userform.  It's probably a bug of some sort.

Comment: A possible workaround might be to create two userforms, with each one having a multipage control.  Then, simply hide and unhide the userforms as needed.

Comment: Thank for your advice , I created more userforms and it works :)

Comment: That's great, glad it worked out.  Cheers!